# A lot of opening/closing of PHP tags

Tags: php

I've always wondered: does having a large open and close PHP (i.e. a template) hurt?

To clarify:

```
 <html>
    <?php echo $test; ?>
    <body <?php echo $test2; ?>>
    <table>
        <?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['cell1']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['cell1']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['cell1']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['cell1']; ?></td>
            <?php echo $row['added cells']; ?>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <?php echo $someMorePhp; ?>
    <div>
        <?php /*do some more php stuff */ ?>
    </div>
    etc etc
    etc
```

Or would it be advisable to i.e.

```
<html>
<php echo $test.'<body'.$test2; ?>>
<table>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$row['cell1'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['cell2'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['cell3'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['cell4'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['cell1'].'</td>
        '.$row['added cells'].'
    <tr>';
    }
</table>
// etc
```

I know this might seem like a micro optimization and such. To be clear i'm looking for a rule-of-thumb not a specific usecase... Will it hurt entering and exiting the php engine during a single script run...

Comment: possible duplicate of [php echo vs open&close tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394478/php-echo-vs-openclose-tag)

Comment: A lot of `<?php ?>` mixed with HTML stuff is a pain to maintain. You second scenario seems better. But, I prefer avoid mixing HTML and PHP with template system like [RainTPL](http://www.raintpl.com/)

Comment: Oops, sorry, better dupe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437144/opening-closing-tags-performance

Comment: I'd highly suggest twig as a template engine. It can be cached for production so in development you see changes immediately but in production it uses cached <?php echo $row['cellXyz'] ?> style tags.
Very efficient, very maintainable and with tons of amazing features.
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: Thanks for the replies... Indeed it seems its a duplicate for the other questions, Thanks @Boann!

Answer (score 0):

No, that is no problem, you should always opt for better readability in this case.

Also think about either activating shorttags if possible (but beware, those might have some sideeffects / problems with XML sytnax as stated in the comments)

```
<? if ($bool) { ?>
    <?= $myVarThatIWantToOutput ?>
<? } ?>
```

Or think about using a template engine like smarty or twig, which restrict you somehow to force splitting of concerns, make some stuff easier (and more readable) and allow caching of compiled templates to make sure you still get the right speed.

Comment: Short open tags may cause errors when using XML and other Markup Languages. I don not think that is good advice :(
Template Engines are good Advice thou and twig is incredible!

Comment: That's actually what I meant by "if possible". In a regular HTML environment shorttags should not be a problem. But I will edit my Answer!